# Batch: how to pass parameters to function inside a batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I have a sample batch script:

```
@echo off

:installed
    echo "checking %1"
    goto :eof

call:installed "aaa"
```

And when I execute this script, I get the `"checking "` output, as if there were no arguments passed.

I'm on Windows 8.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to *rearrange* your program a bit to manipulate the order of execution.

```
@echo off
call: installed "aaa"
goto :eof

:installed
    echo "checking %~1"
    goto :eof
```

Answer (score 2):

parse your file manually:

`@echo off` is executed.

`:installed` the label is ignored

`echo "checking %1"` is executed with empty %1

`goto :eof`  the batchfile terminates.

The rest is never executed.

Just change the order of execution:

```
@echo off
call:installed "aaa" 
goto :eof

:installed
    echo "checking %1"
    goto :eof
```